# haproxy redirect both scheme and location together

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I need to redirect a specific http URL first to its equivalent https and then on to a completely different https URL (don't ask why I can't just redirect the original http straight to the final https URL, this is what the client wants and the client is always right!).  Additionally I need to be able to redirect the original https to the different https too.

So, what I need is the ability to redirect http://foo.bar.com => https://foo.bar.com and then https://foo.bar.com => https://another.foobar.com, as well as redirecting https://foo.bar.com => https://another.foobar.com.

Currently to redirect just https://foo.bar.com => https://another.foobar.com I'm using this:

```
acl is_new_portal hdr(host) -i foo.bar.com
redirect location https://another.foobar.com code 302 if is_new_portal
```

with an initial bind on port 443, and I know to redirect http to https I would use:

```
redirect scheme https code 302 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

(using code 302 rather than 301 as eventually another.foobar.com will be removed, so I don't want the redirection permanently cached in clients' browsers)

but I need to be able to do both relocations, and I'm not sure how you combine the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain to understand if your issue is related to the binding or to the ACLs. You already have all the answers to your question. You can wrap them in a simple frontend:

```
frontend main
  bind :80
  bind :443 ssl crt yourCertFile

  acl is_new_portal hdr(host) -i foo.bar.com
  redirect scheme https code 302 if !{ ssl_fc } is_new_portal
  redirect location https://another.foobar.com code 302 if { ssl_fc } is_new_portal

  http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload; if { ssl_fc }
```

The space between ACLs after the if is interpreted as a AND. So you will get something like:

- redirect to https IF the host is foo.bar.com AND NOT using ssl
- redirect to https://another.foobar.com IF the host is foo.bar.com AND using ssl

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if both redirects would be actioned, thanks for the suggestion.  I also need to work in a `Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000"` setting, but I'm guessing I can just add that into the same frontend.

Comment: @HelenH yep I just added it to my answer. I am no certain that in your case the 'if { ssl_fc }' is needed